# Auto update Android app who is not on App Store

Tags: javascript, android, updates, auto-update

I need some help in Android studio where I am going to make app for a student but I don't have enough money to purchase the developer account I need some help from you I think you will help me

**I want to ask that how can I make the JavaScript for the app that can download the latest version of app in background and notify to install the new version when downloaded is complete**

I'm not very techie person so please give me some demo code for my convenience

If anybody help me I will be thankful from my heart

Comment: "I'm not very techie person so please give me some demo code for my convenience"  That's not how this site works.  You need to make an effort to solve it on your own.  Then you come here and ask for help when you're stuck on a very specific part of the problem.  Then we help.  We aren't going to write your app for you.

Comment: you don't need a developer account to make an android app.

Comment: I know that I don't need to create developer account to make an Android app that's why I'm asking that question how can I send latest version notification to my users and how that will download in background and notified to that person that you need to install that already downloaded updates

Answer (score 0):

Okay after going through Question and the comment, what I have understood is that you want to download the latest version of the app without uploading to google play.

My Answer: You can use Firebase cloud Messaging i.e FCM to send the notification, Once user tap on the notification open the link where you have stored the app and start that process in the background using the service or intent service.

P.S: ask this type of question on Reddit or somewhere else.

Comment: I got it what are you want to say and I already set up that notification manager and I want to know that how can I send the link notification for the update and how can customer or the user will get that update

Comment: What is the need to send the link to the notification? Set the permanent link and store it in-app. And upload the new apk on this link.

Comment: Yeah I know that app store will be send the new App update notification automatically but I don't have the developer account so I want to store that apk on my website and send the link via notification to update the new app from the older version and it will be read I read and download automatically from that location if anybody have that demo code please forward me

Comment: First of all, you need to understand; you don't need the developer account to update the app. I am suggesting that fix the URL or path where you are uploading the newer version of your app, once you upload the new version of the app, send the notification (just a simple notification without URL) and catch it in-app. Once you pick that notification, call service to download the app from the URL ( URL will be stored in the app itself)

Comment: Ok I got it but what if the latest version is already installed what will be going to happen is that the new apps with same version will be downloaded or it will be cancel or auto cancel because of the latest version is already installed

Comment: that I don't know. Figure out yourself and let me know also. I never tried it before. There are lots of ways, manual or automatic.